# Change color depending on background color with Sass

Tags: css, sass, frontend

I want to set up some sass color rules that will automatically choose the font color variable for me. I want the text color to be dependent on what color the background color of the parent div is.

**If**

```
div {background-color: #000; }
```

**Then**

```
div p { color: #fff; }
```

How can this be achieved with sass?

Answer (score 24):

You could use `lightness()` function for the `background-color` to determine the `color` value, as follows:

```css
@function set-color($color) {
    @if (lightness($color) > 40) {
      @return #000;
    }
    @else {
      @return #FFF;
    }
}
```

Then use the above function as below:

```css
div { background-color: black; // Or whatever else }
div p { color: set-color(black); }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9024526)**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [flow control rules](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control).

It depends on the purpose, but there might be easier ways to change a background color depending on a certain condition, such as JavaScript.