# Create grid lines that are visible for any background color CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to write a CSS class for the grid lines of a "canvas" (div element). The user can change the background color of the "canvas", so I need the lines to be visible for every color. At the moment I have the following CSS code:

```
.grid.grid-linear {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(78, 78, 78, .7) 2px, transparent 2px), -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(78, 78, 78, .7) 1px, transparent 2px);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(78, 78, 78, .7) 2px, transparent 2px), -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(78, 78, 78, .7) 1px, transparent 2px);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(78, 78, 78, .7) 2px, transparent 2px), -ms-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(78, 78, 78, .7) 1px, transparent 2px);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(78, 78, 78, .7) 2px, transparent 2px), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(78, 78, 78, .7) 1px, transparent 2px);
}
```

The issue is that when the user selects a background color of: `rgb(78,78,78)` the lines will no longer be visible.

> How can I create the grid lines using **just** CSS or Sass to conform to **any** background color the user selects?

**Note**: The user changes the background color property of the grid (div element) dynamically, so if I were to implement some logic to the Sass file I need to have access to properties of other elements in the DOM. I don't know if doing this in **just** Sass is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color depending on background color with Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802803/change-color-depending-on-background-color-with-sass)

Comment: @MartijnVissers I was going for something that requires very little logic in the code. A hard-coded setting to the linear-gradient function in CSS or SASS that can generate the expected behavior

Comment: Ideally a visible static grid lines that are always visible for any background color. I was just curious if anyone knows if that is possible.

Comment: The linked possible duplicate has such a problem. If the background is dark you can set a light grid and vice versa.

Comment: I have experimented with repeating-radial-gradient and managed to get grid dots that are consistently visible for any background color. Wanted to see if it works for linear-gradient. Nonetheless, I will take a look at your suggestion!

Comment: @MartijnVissers My only issue with that solution is what should I pass as the argument to the set-color() function? background-image: linear-gradient(to right, set-color(...) 2px, transparent 2px), linear-gradient(to bottom,set-color(...) 1px, transparent 2px);

Comment: I think $color should be rgba 78 78 78 0.7 in your case

Comment: The issue with that solution is that it isn't dynamic. For example, rgb(78,78,78) passed to set-color will always return #FFF so it will work for all colors besides white. The user will select different colors and the lines will always be white. I might as well have hard-coded in the color to be white.